# Disable objects in collection for export

Tags: export, collections

I have a collection with multiple objects inside. I instance this collection in a few places. Inside the collections are also a few objects that are just there for practical reasons, like high-poly models and cage objects. I have them marked as not visible and hidden in the render. And when rendering the final scene with the instanced collections, the hidden objects indeed don't appear. But I want to export the scene to gltf. The problem is that even when I enable to include only visible or renderable objects, all objects inside the instanced collections get exported.

Also in the viewport when working on the final scene with the instanced collections the hidden objects appear. It would be cool if they wouldn't appear there too.

One possible solution I found is to just move the objects to not be exported out of the collection, but that would make the whole workflow more complicated.

Does anyone know what is the recommended approach? Maybe I am also doing something completely wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is making more collections, equivalent hierachy tier to the things you want to exclude from export, move the objects to the new collections, then tick "Exclude from view layer" (have the tick in the checkbox off). If you only tick the eye off, it is still be included in exporting.